# Rename hundreds of directories

Tags: command-line, directory, batch-rename

I have more than hundred directories named `SP_[number]_date`. I'd like to rename all to just `SP_[number]`.

I can only figure out how to do that by `mv SP_1_date SP_1` but that will take ages. Can I rename all at once? I thought that I could do something like `for num in ./*; do mv SP_$num_date SP_$num; done` but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: The `rename` expression would be `s/_date$//`

Comment: is `date` literal or is a date, like in `SP_1_May 12, 2015`?

Comment: The reason `mv SP_$num_date SP_$num` didn't work was that you don't have a variable `$num_date` (or, at least, that's one of the reasons).  You would have needed `${num}_date` to separate the variable `$num` from a constant suffix `_date`.  Another problem is that the value in `$num` might be `./SP_1_date` so the `mv` command was attempting to move `SP_./` (since `$num_date` was undefined and hence an empty string) to `SP_./SP_1_date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple enough `bash` way:

```
for i in *_date
do
    mv "$i" "${i%%_date}"
done
```

`${i%%_date}` removes a trailing `_date` from the string in `i`.

Comment: That would be great! So how many % should I add, when the number is up to four digits eg. SP_2200_date?

Comment: @Ditte oh, the `%` is not related to the number of digits. `%%` removes the longest matching suffix , `%` removes the shortest matching suffix. For example, if I did `${i%_*date}`,  I'd get `SP_2200`, and if I did `${i%%_*date}`, I'd get `SP`. In the case of the answer, it makes no difference, as I'm not using any wildcard.

Comment: @Ditte search for `%%` in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: I accidently only wrote one % and now they're all SP_num_date%_date... :(  I can't really understand why I just can't use mv SP_$num_*  SP_$num. Should I change switch the order of the "$i" and "$i%%_date-date" then?

Comment: @Ditte It's `${i%%_date}`! With the braces!