# Delete first part of file names

Tags: rename, batch

I have a directory full of files foo_num.txt. I'd like to rename all to num.txt (that is delete the "foo_" part). Can I do this in one line?

Comment: That is actually going to be the same answer as in your other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/659653/rename-hundreds-of-directories except you change the "mv" command there to fit your new needs.

Comment: By the way: there is a tool called "pyrenamer" where you can do this from the desktop. App: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/pyrenamer/ (it is in Ubuntu software center)

Comment: it's just that I need to move the first part of the name - not the last... does it still function then?

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I can't figure out how to make it work. I guess it's too complex for me. I'll try to do it manually :( Have a nice day and thanks for trying :)

Comment: try pyrenamer It does an amazing job and has some nifty shortcuts for manipulating filenames

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to bother with for-loops in Bash, you might want to use the [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) program:

```
rename "s/foo_//" *.txt
```

The first argument is the Perl expression defining the string replacement rule. In this case: [s]ubstitute "foo_" with "".

The second argument filters the files you want to rename.

Answer (score 1):

As your first part is separated by a `_` I suggest you

```
rename 's/.*?_//' *.txt
```

The `?` means *not greedy*, therefore only the first occurrence of `_` will be replaced.

*Example*

```
$ ls -laog
total 4280
drwxrwxr-x  2 4329472 Aug 10 13:05 .
drwx------ 55   20480 Aug 10 12:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:05 foo_1_1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:05 foo_2_2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:05 foo_3_3.txt

$ rename 's/.*?_//' *.txt

$ ls -laog
total 4280
drwxrwxr-x  2 4329472 Aug 10 13:06 .
drwx------ 55   20480 Aug 10 12:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:05 1_1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:05 2_2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:05 3_3.txt
```

---

To replace all occurrences use

```
rename 's/.*_//' *.txt
```

*Example*

```
$ ls -laog
total 4280
drwxrwxr-x  2 4329472 Aug 10 13:08 .
drwx------ 55   20480 Aug 10 12:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:08 foo_1_1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:08 foo_2_2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:08 foo_3_3.txt

$ rename 's/.*_//' *.txt

$ ls -laog
total 4280
drwxrwxr-x  2 4329472 Aug 10 13:09 .
drwx------ 55   20480 Aug 10 12:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:08 1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:08 2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Aug 10 13:08 3.txt
```

Comment: First answer and best answer...  Dunno why the other one got so many upvotes!  **;-)**